# How can I call a void function in a cout statement?

Tags: c++

I am trying to print out the mark and the letter grade on the same line but I am unable to call a void function in the cout statement, is there a way to do this? Also I understand I can call it on the next line after the cout statement but I need them to print on the same line.

```
void printLetterGrade(float mark)
{
    float grade = mark;

    if (grade >= 90)
        cout << "Your Letter Grade is A+" << endl;

    else if ((grade >= 85) && (grade <= 89))
        cout << "Your Letter Grade is A" << endl;

    else 
        cout << "fail" << endl;

}

float calculateClassStats(float marks[], int length)
{
    const int arrayCount = length;
    for (int x = 0; x < arrayCount; x++){
        char letter = printLetterGrade(marks[x]);
        cout << marks[x] << letter << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to print a void function? Either call the function before the print or change the return type.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the `printLetterGrade` such that it *does* return something. E.g.

```
const char *printLetterGrade(float mark)
{
   if ( ... )
      return "A+";
   if ( ... )
      return "A";
   ...
}
```

(Of course, at this point, you may want to call the function something else too)

Comment: This is the most reasonable answer. `std::cout << "Your letter grade is " << getLetterGrade(mark) << " with a grade of " << mark << '\n';`

Comment: Would there be a way to print both on the same line without changing my void function ?

Comment: Yes, add a cout statement in your void function and call it after the cout statement in your calculateClassStats function.

Comment: Yes, you could simply break your original `cout` statment, call the void-function to print it's stuff, and then do the rest of the printing. Just remove the `endl` as well, so that it ends up on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Print both in same function

```
void printLetterGrade(float mark)
{
    float grade = mark;

    if (grade >= 90)
        cout <<mark<< "Your Letter Grade is A+" << endl;

    else if ((grade >= 85) && (grade <= 89))
        cout <<mark<< "Your Letter Grade is A" << endl;

    else 
        cout << "fail" << endl;

}

float calculateClassStats(float marks[], int length)
{
    const int arrayCount = length;
    for (int x = 0; x < arrayCount; x++){
        printLetterGrade(marks[x]);            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print something on the same line, just don't print the `endl`:

```
void printLetterGrade(float mark)
{
    float grade = mark;

    if (grade >= 90)
        cout << "Your Letter Grade is A+" << endl;

    else if ((grade >= 85) && (grade <= 89))
        cout << "Your Letter Grade is A" << endl;

    else 
        cout << "fail" << endl;

}

float calculateClassStats(float marks[], int length)
{
    const int arrayCount = length;
    for(int x = 0; x < arrayCount; x++) {

        cout << marks[x] << " "; // don't print endl, just a space
        printLetterGrade(marks[x]); // goes on same line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not `cout` the result of a `void` function or cast the `void` to something to be used on the `cout`, since there is nothing being returned.

If all you needed is the side effect of your function `printLetterGrade` and that the side effect take place exactly at a certain point in the `cout` sequence, you can change its return to something trivial that does not print,

e.g., You can change the return type from `void` to `char *` or `string` and return an empty string `""` wherever you had a `return;` statement (if any).

Answer (score 0):

```
float calculateClassStats(float marks[], int length)
{
    const int arrayCount = length;
    for (int x = 0; x < arrayCount; x++)
    {

        cout << marks[x] << printLetterGrade(marks[x]) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just change the return-type to `string`, and change `cout <<` to `return`.

```
string printLetterGrade(float mark)
{
    float grade = mark;

    if (grade >= 90)
        return " Your Letter Grade is A+";

    else if ((grade >= 85) && (grade <= 89))
        return " Your Letter Grade is A";

    else 
        return " Fail";

}
```

Output

```
95 Your Letter Grade is A+
88 Your Letter Grade is A
50 Fail
```

Answer (score -1):

modify your cout statement as

```
 cout<<printLetterGrade(marks[x])<<marks[x];
```

Also remove the `char letter = printLetterGrade(marks[x]);`line, it seems unnecessary.

Edit: the modified code will then be:

```
void printLetterGrade(float mark)
{
float grade = mark;

if (grade >= 90)
    cout << "Your Letter Grade is A+" << endl;

else if ((grade >= 85) && (grade <= 89))
    cout << "Your Letter Grade is A" << endl;

else 
    cout << "fail" << endl;

}

float calculateClassStats(float marks[], int length)
{
const int arrayCount = length;
for (int x = 0; x < arrayCount; x++){
    cout<<marks[x];
    printLetterGrade(marks[x]); 
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: this would give me an error saying 'cannot convert printlettergrade() to type const unsigned  char

Comment: remove char letter = printLetterGrade(marks[x]);
If you want to print the grade too, use a cout statement in the printLetterGrade function instead.

Comment: Consider returning an instance of the output stream, similar to overloading `operator <<`.